# My code for finding the longest word does not work

Tags: javascript

```
    function findLongestWord(str){
  var array = str.split(" ");
  var long = array[0].length;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(long < array[i].length){
      long = array[i];
    }
  }
  return long;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I was already given the solution to this problem; but, I wanted to know why this program does give the longest word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to following

- Update `var long = array[0].length;` to `var long = array[0];` (**store value**)
- In if condition, update `long <` to `long.length <` (**compare length**)

```js
 function findLongestWord(str){
  var array = str.split(" ");
  var long = array[0]; 
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(long.length < array[i].length){
      long = array[i];
    }
  }
  return long;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: @SkillnovationLy - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to use `long.length` in if block.

```
function findLongestWord(str){
  var array = str.split(" ");
  var long = array[0];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(long.length < array[i].length){
      long = array[i];
    }
  }
  return long;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```js
findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");


function findLongestWord(str) {
  const arr = str.split(' ').map(e => e.length);
  const idx = Math.max(...arr);
  console.log(str.split(' ')[arr.indexOf(idx)]);
}
```